GraphQL Connector Object to ID mapping rookie question
I'm working on setting up an Elasticsearch GraphQL connector from Kibana UI. I am trying to index a small test data and I'm stuck on "Object to ID mapping".
The test query ("GraphQL Body"):
query getProduktListing {
    getProduktListing(first: 10, after: 0) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}

The response I am trying to map looks like this (Postman output for the query):
{
    "data": {
        "getProduktListing": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "138"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "140"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "144"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "id": "156"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

As you can see, the result comes in as an array (edges), which means that a straightforward solution (putting {"getItemListing.edges.node":"id"} into "GraphQL Connector Object to ID" textbox will not work.

I tried with a different query as a "GraphQL Body", i.e.
query GetProdukt($id: Int) {
    getProdukt(id: $id) {
        id
    }
}


But I did not know how to put multiple ids as "GraphQL variable" in order to get more than one product/Document out of it.

I'm new to both - GraphQL and Elastic, so please take this into account, I might have missed something obvious.
Misc. details about the setup:

Self managed Docker'ized setup
Elasticsearch version 8.15.0
Will provide more details if needed

